# AFNetworking downloading multiple files memory footprint

Tags: objective-c, ios, afnetworking

I'm using ARC and I'm have an issue downloading multiple files (10000+) in my app when using AFNetworking. I'm creating each AFHTTPRequest and then queuing them to be executed. When I run this using instruments, I can see the memory usage increasing and increasing until the all the files have been downloaded, only then is all the memory released. This survives on the simulator, but crashes when running on an iOS device.

Below is a sample code of what i'm doing

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_FILES_TO_DOWNLOAD; i++) {
    _imageCounter++;
    [self downloadFile:i];
}

- (void)downloadFile:(NSUInteger)num
{    
    NSString *fileURL = @"file/%d/", num];
    NSURLRequest *url = [self.httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:fileURL parameters:nil];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [_httpClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:url success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     ...
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     ...
    }];

    [_httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:requestOperation];    
}
```

It appears that the files(`responseObject`) aren't being released after the operation success block is executed and that is what is continually increasing the memory footprint? Is this correct? Am I using the AFNetworking and the operationQueue as intended?

Comment: so what was the solution then?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put an @autoreleasepool inside your for loop.

Comment: Don't think this would work. The files are getting passed to the success block asynchronously. Creating a autorelease pool inside the for loop wouldn't help